# Стиль кнопки как в Windows

Tags: html, css, button, style

Как сделать такой же стиль кнопки при наведении ?

[image: Кнопка]

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4375255/1548895

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Взято из [ответа c enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4375548/1548895).

```css
a.button {
    height: 18px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #707070;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #707070;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2 0%, #EBEBEB 50%, #DDDDDD 51%, #CFCFCF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0,#F2F2F2), color-stop(0.5,#EBEBEB),color-stop(0.51,#DDDDDD),color-stop(1,#CFCFCF));
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2 0%, #EBEBEB 50%, #DDDDDD 51%, #CFCFCF 100%);
    font: normal 12px sans-serif;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ECF7FD;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #3C7FB1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #3C7FB1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #3C7FB1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EAF6FD 0%, #D9F0FC 50%, #BEE6FD 51%, #A7D9F5 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0,#EAF6FD), color-stop(0.5,#D9F0FC),color-stop(0.51,#BEE6FD),color-stop(1,#A7D9F5));
    background: linear-gradient(top, #EAF6FD 0%, #D9F0FC 50%, #BEE6FD 51%, #A7D9F5 100%);
}
a.button:active {
    padding: 2px 7px 3px 9px;
    border: 1px solid #73A7C4;
    border-bottom: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #2C628B;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #2C628B;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #2C628B;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E5F4FC 0%, #C4E5F6 50%, #98D1EF 51%, #68B3DB 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0,#E5F4FC), color-stop(0.5,#C4E5F6),color-stop(0.51,#98D1EF),color-stop(1,#68B3DB));
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Click me</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aUsxy/1/

Comment: В большинстве случаев вендорные префиксы в примере уже совсем неактуальны.